# Could someone explain me the Contourlet Decomposition level?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I don't understand Contourlet decomposition level. Please explain me the following codes in MATLAB. 
`nlevels=[0,2,3,4]
nlevels=[2]`

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with contourlet decomposition (although that variable may be used later in the code for that purpose) - it simply assigns a 4-value vector to the variable `nlevels`, and then re-assigns a 1-value vector to the same variable...

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided enough details of the code, but here is a general idea about levels of decomposition:

The main difference between wavelets, contourlets, surfacelets, X-lets is how they divide the frequency space at each level.

Wavelet is a multi-resolution transform and at each level divides the 2-D frequency space into 4 equal part like this

[image]

So as you see, At each level we have four equal squares.

Contourlets differ from wavelets by the way they divide the frequency space, here is a two level decomposition:

[image]

So at each level you take the low frequency part and continue decomposing it, while for the high frequency part you do a directional decomposition.

Surfacelets, on the other hand, go beyond 2-D and divide the 3-D frequency space, I can add more details if you are interested.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your nice answer, but I think in the above you showed two level Contourlet decomposition where level-2 has been started after downsampling by factor 2. Am I right? You wrote one level decomposition but it's two level Contourlet decomposition and so on. right?

Comment: Oh, you are right. why did I write one level?!! As you pointed out it shows two levels

Comment: It did not answer your question on the coding side. I can not guess what nlevels is used for in your code, it could be for number of levels of decomposition, it could also be whether at each level we decompose both high and low frequencies.